# Application keeps crashing , after i changed my theme in AndroidManifest file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-theme

when I change the application theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the app crash!

here is the XML code I used:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.activity101">
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Show us the error you get and edit your question with information/code of what you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Theme in your Styles.xml first

for example

```
    <style name="Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>
```

Then you set this Theme on the Activity you want it to show on. like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.activity101">
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Hope this helps.